# Comments for each post on home page DIVI theme?

Tags: comments, wordpress-theming

I want to add comment box for each post in my home page like a single page i try to insert   before while in index.php but it dont work 
Please ansure if you use DIVI theme becouse i try diferent way..

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: the_content();
else
the_content();   
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
THIS I ADD 
if ( ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) && 'on' == et_get_option( 'divi_show_postcomments', 'on' ) )
comments_template( '', true );
?>  
</article> <!-- .et_pb_post -->
i take this code for comments from single,php